# How do I overwrite existing items with Folder.CopyHere in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I run the following to unzip and want to overwrite the current files if they exist but the [Microsoft solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723207%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't seem to work.  I haven't found anything that says it works so is there a work around to select the 'yes to all' option?

```
$zipPackage = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($zipfilename)
$destinationFolder = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($destination)
$destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items(),16)
```

Answer (score 54):

If you want it to overwrite AND be silent change `0x10` to `0x14` ([docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176633.aspx)).

```
$destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items(), 0x14)
```

Comment: The flags work when extracting a zip file to a folder, which is what the OP is doing in his example, but seem to be ignored when creating a zip file :(

Comment: Just a head up, the special Fonts folder does not honor overloads passed in the CopyHere method.

Comment: @FoxDeploy, thanks for the heads-up about the Fonts folder.

Comment: I came here for the fonts folder :|

Answer (score 1):

My pragmatic remedy for this issue would be to use something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Which has a nice commandline interface easily used from within PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry, I can't change the zip app.  So is there no way around the microsoft blunder?