# Powershell script for download files and unziping it

Tags: powershell

I found PS script (below) for downloading ZIP file from ULR and unzipping it in specific file.

```
$Url = "www.link.com/test.zip"
$DownloadZipFile = "D:\Test" + $(Split-Path -Path $Url -Leaf)
$ExtractPath = "D:\Test"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -OutFile $DownloadZipFile
$ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$ExtractFiles = $ExtractShell.Namespace($DownloadZipFile).Items() 
$ExtractShell.NameSpace($ExtractPath).CopyHere($ExtractFiles) 
Start-Process $ExtractPath
#
```

This works fine but I have problem if same file already exists in this folder.
So, I need to add if file exist to overwrite this file with new file. Can someone can help me?

Rgds, Nejc

Comment: Does this answer your question? `.CopyHere($ExtractFiles, 0x10)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359372/how-do-i-overwrite-existing-items-with-folder-copyhere-in-powershell/5711383

Comment: Yes this works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if file exist and delete it.

```
if (Test-Path $DownloadZipFile)
{
    Remove-Item -Path $DownloadZipFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Url = "www.link.com/test.zip"
$DownloadZipFile = "D:\Test" + $(Split-Path -Path $Url -Leaf)
$ExtractPath = "D:\Test"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -OutFile $DownloadZipFile
$ExtractShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$ExtractFiles = $ExtractShell.Namespace($DownloadZipFile).Items() 
$ExtractShell.NameSpace($ExtractPath).CopyHere($ExtractFiles, ***0x10***) 
Start-Process $ExtractPath
#
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).